# How to move the blue twitter bird slowly using css and js?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to make the little bird **fly** back from the tree? it goes forward now, i want it to turn and come back...how to do it?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".bird").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass("birdmove");
  })
});
```

```css
.bird img{
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
}

.bird{
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top: 100px;
  z-index: 10;
  transition: transform 5s;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
}

.birdmove{
  transform: translateX(800px);
  animation: oscillate 5s;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
}
@keyframes oscillate {
  10% {top: 50px;}
  30% {top: 150px;}
  60% {top: 100px;}
  80% {top: 120px;}
  100% {top: 100px;}
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>preloader</title>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="preloader.css">
   <script type="text/javascript" src="preloader.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
 

 <div class ="container">
  <div class = "row">
   <div class="col-sm-8">
    <div class="bird">
     <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/9/9f/Twitter_bird_logo_2012.svg/1259px-Twitter_bird_logo_2012.svg.png" height="300" width="500" >
     
    </div>
   </div>
     <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="static-bird">
       <img src="https://clipartion.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/love-birds-in-tree-clipart.jpeg">
          </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   
</body>
```

? While the other bird in branch will be static! How to animate it using CSS and JavaScript?

Thanks in advance !

[image]

Comment: You can Use CSS3 and JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using CSS3 **animation** and **transformation** only and little jQuery to add a class and start the translation, if you don't want to make it very complex.

I have used two motions for bird to fly: 1 in X direction, other in Y direction. Both images are positioned absolute.

Here's the full code. You can change it accordingly:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".bird").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass("birdmove");
  })
});
```

```css
.bird img{
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
}
.static-bird img{
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
}
.bird{
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top: 100px;
  z-index: 10;
  transition: transform 5s;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
}
.static-bird{
  position: absolute;
  right: 200px;
  top: 100px;
  z-index: 5;
}
.birdmove{
  transform: translateX(800px);
  animation: oscillate 5s;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
}
@keyframes oscillate {
  10% {top: 50px;}
  30% {top: 150px;}
  60% {top: 100px;}
  80% {top: 120px;}
  100% {top: 100px;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class ="container">
  <div class = "row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <div class="bird">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/9/9f/Twitter_bird_logo_2012.svg/1259px-Twitter_bird_logo_2012.svg.png" height="300" width="500">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="static-bird">
        <img src="https://clipartion.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/love-birds-in-tree-clipart.jpeg">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How to modify the code if I want the bird to fly as soon as I enter into HTML page ? Not when i click the bird..

Comment: You'd need JavaScript for that. You can't use transformation without any event.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot :) i have a doubt, now it flies forward, if i want it to chnage direction and flyback to the starting position, what should i do?

Comment: As I wrote, if you want to make the animation complex, use JavaScript. You can use `setInterval` and `setTimeout` methods to control the animations. Use JavaScript animations. http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_animate.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can add a [CSS animation](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp) to the `.bird` selector that specifies how the bird should fly. To make sure the animation is smooth, make sure you use the hardware-accelerated [transform](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp) property, like so:

```
@keyframes hover {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(0, -15px, 0);
  }

  100% {
    transform: translate3d(0, +15px, 0);
  }
}

.bird {
  animation: hover 2s ease-in-out infinite reverse;
}
```

This will make the bird hover vertically.

Answer (score 0):

look at below example :

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: 1px solid black;
  -webkit-transition: all 750ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 750ms ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 750ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 750ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 750ms ease-in-out;
}
div:hover {
  -moz-transform: translateX(200px) translateY(40px);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(200px) translateY(40px);
  -o-transform: translateX(200px) translateY(40px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(200px) translateY(40px);
  transform: translateX(200px) translateY(40px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

  <div></div>

</body>

</html>
```